# Two of my potato plants stalks are wilting, but the other is not

Tags: potatoes, wilt

We are growing potatoes in pots, and have one pot where the potato has grown three stalks. Two of them have wilted and appear to be dying, while the third, from the same potato, is completely fine and looks healthy. Is there any reason this is occuring?

Attached an image, sorry for the low quality.
[image: The potato plants (sorry for the low image quality my phone camera isn't the best)]

Answer (score 2):

It might just be damping off disease, which is a common ailment for young plants, if the soil or water is infected. Usually the plants that survive are fine.

I would suspect a problem with your soil or water. Either disease (such as Pythium, Verticillium, Fusarium, etc.) or herbicide. Too much salt or such in the water might also be a problem.

The remaining plant does look like it could possibly be suffering from effects of herbicide. Yes, it is a live and standing, but the leaves are wispy, small and sparse-looking. Hopefully it's fine. If there's nothing wrong with it, it could probably use some phosphorus and other nutrients (as well as increased light) to help the leaves size up.

Overwatering, or soil that doesn't drain properly could potentially be the issue, alternatively.